# WPF Listbox: does HasItemSelected event exist somehow?

Tags: wpf, events, listbox

I'm using a ListBox in WPF, and I want to enable/disable a button only when an item from the ListBox is actually selected.

The problem is that my button does an action that retrieves the name of the item, and since at initialisation, no item is selected (and I want to keep it that way), I'm getting an error because I'm performing logic on a null object ...

I really looked around and I couldn't find one =/

Have a nice day =)

Comment: some source code would be nice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

make a [value converter](http://www.switchonthecode.com/tutorials/wpf-tutorial-binding-converters) and bind the buttons `IsEnabled` to the `SelectedIndex` of the `Listbox` using the converter.

```
public class MyConverter : IValueConverter
{
  public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
  {
    int ndx = (int)value;
    if ( ndx < 0 ) return false;
    return true;
  }

  public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
  {
    return null;
  }
}


<Window.Resources>
    <my:MyConverter x:Name="MyConverter"/>
</Window.Resources>

<ListBox x:Name="MyListBox"></ListBox>
<Button IsEnabled="{Binding Path=SelectedIndex, ElementName=MyListBox, Converter={StaticResource MyConverter}}"/>
```

Comment: Can you give me an example? I'm not familiar with value converters =/

Comment: @FatalBaboon, I am on it :)  also, check out the link for the Switch On The Code article.

Comment: Why is there a ComboBox in your answer? I'm using a ListBox.

Comment: I'm confused on where would a button be in a ListBox, which property of the ListBox do I use the converter on?

Comment: Mmmmh, I think I'm starting to get this actually :p

Comment: Didn't you mean if( ndx <0 ) return false; ?

Comment: Also, I use merged resource dictionaries, so I'm gonna put this into the lowest level one, but "<my:" is not recognized.

Comment: Ok i slightly changed it to :
    <Window.Resources>
        <local:ConverterListBoxSelection x:Key="ConverterListBoxSelection"/>
    </Window.Resources>
IsEnabled="{Binding Path=SelectedIndex, ElementName=listBoxAvailableReplays, Converter={StaticResource ConverterListBoxSelection}}

That and what previously said about the int-->ndx.

Correct it and I'll accept your answer =)

Comment: @fatalbaboon, this was a truncated example, you will have to add the xmlns, etc :)